# Performance Difference between HttpContext user and Thread user

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance, vb.net-2010

I am wondering what the difference between `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString.ToLower` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString.ToLower`. Both methods grab the username in my asp.net 3.5 web service. I decided to figure out if there was any difference in performance using a little program. Running from full Stop to Start Debugging in every run.

```
Dim st As DateTime = DateAndTime.Now
        Try
            'user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString.ToLower
            user = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString.ToLower
            Dim dif As TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(st)
            Dim break As String = "nothing"

        Catch ex As Exception
            user = "Undefined"
        End Try
```

I set a breakpoint on break to read the value of `dif`. The results were the same for both methods.

```
    dif.Milliseconds    0   Integer

    dif.Ticks           0   Long
```

Using a longer duration, loop 5,000 times results in these figures.

Thread Method

```
        run 1
    dif.Milliseconds    125     Integer
    dif.Ticks           1250000 Long

        run 2 
    dif.Milliseconds    0   Integer
    dif.Ticks   0   Long

        run 3 
    dif.Milliseconds    0   Integer
    dif.Ticks   0   Long
```

HttpContext Method

```
        run 1
    dif.Milliseconds    15  Integer
    dif.Ticks   156250  Long

        run 2
    dif.Milliseconds    156 Integer
    dif.Ticks   1562500 Long

        run 3
    dif.Milliseconds    0   Integer
    dif.Ticks   0   Long
```

So I guess what is more prefered, or more compliant with webservice standards? If there is some type of a performance advantage, I can't really tell. Which one scales to larger environments easier?

Answer (score 0):

Your test shows that the difference is miniscule at most, but please take note of [SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx)

Also, if that is representative of the actual code, do you really need a Try..Catch or could you use the preferred method which is to test for `Is Nothing` on the appropriate entities which could be nothing?